# What are all the ways I should let my users invoke the toolbar in a Metro app?

Tags: discovery, windows-8, metro

I'm playing around with the Windows 8 Developer preview, with the intention of making a Metro version of an existing product. It seems that in the Metro apps included with the preview, the toolbar is invoked by pressing the right mouse button. I'm not sure if there are other ways, I haven't discovered them if so, or found any published guidelines.

My app cannot use the right mouse button in this way (the app is fullscreen, and uses the right-mouse button), but I'd like to still use the native toolbar. How can I let my users know the toolbar is there, and how should they be able to invoke it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know its intended by UX design to give right mouse click the context menu of either the app, if nothing is marked or, if marked, context menu of this item. But you get still quite vague information about this.
By touch context menu is a swipe from top or bottom of outer borders.

- [Windows Dev - Guidelines for user interaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465370.aspx)
- [Channel 9 UX Video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/BPS-1004)